# Paginating Geo-Data with high performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am building a backend (.NET 5 WebApi via REST) for a mobile app.
We have a few million entries in the database (Azure SQL Server) which all have a geolocation.
The app should query them sorted by the current location.
In addition, this should be paged, so e.g. take the first 30 results with the first call, then the next 30, etc.

I cannot come up with a really clever solution.
My current code for the third page of 30 entries looks like that:

```
data.OrderBy(p => p.Location.Distance(currentLocation)).skip(60).take(30).toListAsync()
```

The problem is that even if I know that I need only 30 results, the query needs to order the full table.
I know I can boost it with an index, but does anyone have a hint how to optimize this LINQ code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a lot you are providing here. What's the database, what's the bottle neck exactly, how does the executed query look like, what have you tried so far etc. i.e. I don't see any where condition, so the question is why? You surely don't wanna query **ALL** the data and rather limit it to a max distance (i..e  5000 km/miles from your location prob makesl ittle sense to the person searching)

Comment: Sorry - Mentioned "sql-server" int the tag but forgot to add it to the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this part looks suspect:  `p.Location.Distance(currentLocation)`. If this is running EF Core 2.x then my guess is this would be triggering client-side evaluation resulting in all data being queried back prior to the sorting and pagination. I would recommend hooking up a profiler to the database and reviewing the SQL that is actually being run.

To better arrange sorting by distance I would consider something like:

```
var x = currentLocation.X;
var y = currentLocation.Y;

var results = await data.OrderBy(p => Math.Abs(p.Location.X - x) + Math.Abs(p.Location.Y - y))
    .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This ensures the sorting is done DB server-side. (Though make sure `data` is still an `IQueryable`.)  Substitute X/Y with Lat/Long or whatever coordinate fields you are using.

This doesn't give you the distance, but it gives you a value relative to the distance for each point to compare against other points.  To get the distance would be `Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p.Location.X - x,2) + Math.Pow(Location.Y - y,2))`. I believe EF will translate that to SQL, at least for SQL Server's provider. It's more math conversion to put into an SQL Search which can't be indexed, but that might be more useful if you want to return the distance with the results.